# Trouble understanding An excerpt from 'Effective Java' about compareTo

Tags: java, oop, object, compareto

This is about the compareTo contract that classes can implement.

> there is no way to extend an instantiable class with a new value
>   component while preserving the compareTo contract, unless you are
>   willing to forgo the benefits of object-oriented abstraction. The same
>   workaround applies, too. If you want to add a value component to a
>   class that implements Comparable, don’t extend it; write an unrelated
>   class containing an instance of the first class. Then provide a “view”
>   method that returns this instance. This frees you to implement
>   whatever compareTo method you like on the second class, while allowing
>   its client to view an instance of the second class as an instance of
>   the first class when needed.

I have read [Why can't I extend an instantiable class with a new value component while preserving the compareTo contract?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13509286/why-cant-i-extend-an-instantiable-class-with-a-new-value-component-while-preser). It helped answer one or two questions i had.But the below question still remains unanswered to me.

1) If i define the two classes as unrelated,i am free to implement the compareTo method as i want.Agree that.But how am i making the two classes have the is-a/parent-child relationship.Can someone explain whatever Joshua called the "view" method?

Comment: You don't, that's the point.You implement a has-a relationship instead.

Comment: @JBNizet You should expand on your comment a bit and post it as the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can someone explain whatever Joshua called the "view" method?

I will continue Jon Skeet's simple example from the [answer that you linked in your post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13509469/335858):

```
// In Jon's code, Person derives from NamedThing
class NamedThing {
    String name;
}

class Person extends NamedThing {
    Date dateOfBirth;
}
```

"Providing a view" rather than "extending" would mean designing your class hierarchy like this:

```
class NamedThing {
    String name;
}

class Person {
    private  NamedThing namedThing;
    // Here is the view method
    public NamedThing asNamedThing() {
        return namedThing;
    }
    // Here is a convenience method for accessing name directly
    public String getName() {
        return namedThing.name;
    }
    Date dateOfBirth;
}
```

This frees you up to implement a new `compareTo` inside the `Person`, because there is no requirement to stay compatible with the superclass. If you need to view your person as a `NamedThing`, call `asNamedThing()` to get a view of the person reduced to a thing with a name.

Note that since this is not an is-a relationship, the `asNamedThing` is somewhat misleading: you get the named thing inside the person, not the person who happens to be a named thing. This limits the applicability of `compareTo`: for example, you cannot sort persons among other `NamedThing`s.

Comment: I couldn't think of a way to do the following with this approach.  NamedThing thing = new Person(). Are you saying this syntax while creating person objects is not possible with this approach?

Comment: @AnushaPachunuri Correct, that is one consequence of this approach. You need to do `Person p = new Person(); NamedThing personsThing = p.asNamedThing();`

Comment: And i can still use all polymorphism concepts as is?Lets say dynamic binding in method overriding? They are still achievable right?

Comment: @AnushaPachunuri No, I think that's the point Joshua was trying to make: do not extend `Comparable` classes to add value components to it, leave the class as is. There would be no polymorphism with these new classes and the `Comparable` classes they contain.